# How to replace it smoothly in using jQuery replaceWith()

Tags: jquery, html

CODE:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var replace_div = '<div><input/></div>';
  $('#btn_test').click(function() {
    $('#btn_test').fadeOut('', function() {
      $('#btn_test').replaceWith(replace_div);
    });
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="padding: 40px;">
  <button id="btn_test">test_btn</button>
</div>
```

It has some rigidity during replacing.

I think there is good way to use `fadeIn()`, but don't know how to do it.

Could you help me to make it replace smoothly?

Comment: If this is the actual markup, then it is invalid: _"The [`SCRIPT`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1) element places a script within a document. This element may appear any number of times **in the HEAD or BODY** of an HTML document."_

Comment: It does work smoothly, so what is your actual concern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The div needs to be hidden at first to be able to apply fade in. The `div` is inside another `div` so you can select it with `$('div > div')` and use hide function on it then use fade in then voila.

```js
var replace_div = '<div><input/></div>';
$('#btn_test').click(function () {
  $('#btn_test').fadeOut('', function () {
    $('#btn_test').replaceWith(replace_div);
    $('div > div').hide().fadeIn(1000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="padding: 40px;">
  <button id="btn_test">test_btn</button>
  <br>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks you for answer. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

There is another way which may probably best suitable as per your requirement.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn_test").on("click", function(e) {
    $(this).fadeOut(1000);
    $(".text_div").fadeIn(1000);
  });

});
```

```css
#btn_test {
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height:18px;
  width:120px;
}

.text_div {
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  transition: .3s ease-out-in;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="padding: 40px;">
  <button id="btn_test">Click me</button>
  <div class="text_div">
    <input/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @touchingtwist It would be nice here to help and solve the problems of people, that is only a goal :)